# Search HTML for 2 phrases (ignoring all tags) and strip everything else

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I have html code stored in a string, example:

```
$html = '
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
```

Then I have two sentences stored in variables:

```
$begin = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';
```

I want to search `$html` for these two sentences, and strip everything before and after them. So `$html` will become:

```
$html = 'Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.';
```

How can I achieve this? Note that the `$begin` and `$end` variables do not have html tags but the sentences in `$html` very likely do have tags as shown above.

Maybe a **regex** approach?

## What I've tried so far

- A `strpos()` approach. The problem is that `$html` contains tags in the sentences, making the `$begin` and `$end` sentences not match. I can `strip_tags($html)` before running `strpos()`, but then I will obviously end up with `$html` without the tags.
- Search part of variable, like `Hello`, but that's never safe and will give many matches.

Comment: Interesting question, I think regex is your best bet. Btw, this is how questions should be asked, with a "what I tried so far" section. +1

Comment: Given the complexity of my question, I will start a bounty of 50 points once it's eligible.

Comment: Have you tried ``preg_replace_callback`` php function ?

Comment: @hamism No, please feel free to post an answer outlining your approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim007 you are hard coding everything..that's not good approach

Comment: By `<p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.<p>`, do you mean `<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span>.</p>`? And I don't understand why `.` should be remain.

Comment: Why dont close p tags?

Comment: `.*(<.*?Hello.*?進撃の巨人.*?Lorem.*?ipsum.*?>).*` https://regex101.com/r/tV0eO5/1

Comment: @Tim007 This will work in *this very example* but not generally, please the updated text: https://regex101.com/r/tV0eO5/2

Comment: does words in `Hello 進撃の巨人!` should be continuous (ignoring the tags)

Comment: @rock321987 I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking if the content of $begin should match with the sentence in $html (ignoring tags), then yes, I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: I am asking if `Hello <p> abcd </p> 進撃の巨人!` acceptable by `$begin`

Comment: @rock321987 No, but `Hello <p>  </p> 進撃<em>の巨</人!</em>` should match.

Comment: Do you have have a class or some other kind of identifier, to speed up the process. If you, e.g. know that its always <p> tag, its atleast something. Otherwise you would have to search inside each tag.

Comment: @Borna Unfortunately no. If I had an ID/Class identifier, life would be a lot easier. The tags are completely random.

Comment: So it isnt always a <p> tag?

Comment: @Borna Correct. It could be `<header>Hello <p> </p> 進撃<em>の巨</人!</em></header>`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: If there is `<p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>       random code <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>` what should be the output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good question, the output should be: `Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p> random code <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p> random code <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p> <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.`

Comment: Do you really need HTML tags in the result? If not, it whould be better to strip tags first, then you could find the sentences easily.

Comment: @DávidHorváth Yes, HTML tags are required, otherwise I could easily solve it myself as I outlined in my "what I tried so far" section. ;)

Comment: I also played with a regex approach a bit more where I have time now and came up with [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cE9eI1/3) which is generated [by this php script](https://eval.in/555661) (eval.in). I think there are too many cases to be considered.

Comment: This `and strip everything before and after`  is not what is done in the `will become` text. Writing regular expressions is a matter of _detail_ more than anything else. If you can't be clear about things, why ask the question ? Voting for close is not an option.

Comment: Note that you could end up with HTML that has unbalanced tags. What if your search string starts/ends half way a paragraph? What will you do with that?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, you have attributed the bounty, but could you also accept an answer? NB: I am of course disappointed that you went for a regular expression solution, which personally I am convinced is the wrong approach ;-). But anyway: please also accept an answer so this question is resolved.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a short, yet - I believe - working solution based on a lazy dot matching regex (that can be improved by creating a longer, unrolled regex, but should be enough unless you have really large chunks of text).

```
$html = "<html>\n<body>\n<p><p>H<div>ello</div><script></script> <em>進&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;撃の巨人</em>!</p>\nrandom code\nrandom code\n<p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>\n</body>\n </html>";
$begin = 'Hello     進撃の巨人!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';
$begin = preg_replace_callback('~\s++(?!\z)|(\s++\z)~u', function ($m) { return !empty($m[1]) ? '' : ' '; }, $begin);
$end = preg_replace_callback('~\s++(?!\z)|(\s++\z)~u', function ($m) { return !empty($m[1]) ? '' : ' '; }, $end);
$begin_arr = preg_split('~(?=\X)~u', $begin, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$end_arr = preg_split('~(?=\X)~u', $end, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$reg = "(?s)(?:<[^<>]+>)?(?:&#?\\w+;)*\\s*" .  implode("", array_map(function($x, $k) use ($begin_arr) { return ($k < count($begin_arr) - 1 ? preg_quote($x, "~") . "(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\\w+;))*" : preg_quote($x, "~"));}, $begin_arr, array_keys($begin_arr)))
        . "(.*?)" . 
        implode("", array_map(function($x, $k) use ($end_arr) { return ($k < count($end_arr) - 1 ? preg_quote($x, "~") . "(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\\w+;))*" : preg_quote($x, "~"));}, $end_arr, array_keys($end_arr))); 
echo $reg .PHP_EOL;
preg_match('~' . $reg . '~u', $html, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BVumTS)

Algorithm:

- Create a dynamic regex pattern by splitting the delimiter strings into single graphemes (since these can be Unicode characters, I suggest using `preg_split('~(?<!^)(?=\X)~u', $end)`) and imploding back by adding an optional tag matching pattern `(?:<[^<>]+>)?`.
- Then, `(?s)` enables a DOTALL mode when `.` matches any character including a newline, and `.*?` will match 0+ characters from the leading to trailing delimiter.

*Regex details*:

- `'~(?<!^)(?=\X)~u` matches every location other than at the start of the string before each grapheme
- (sample final regex) `(?s)(?:<[^<>]+>)?(?:&#?\w+;)*\s*H(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*e(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*l(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*l(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*o(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))* (?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*進(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*撃(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*の(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*巨(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*人(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*\!(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*` + `(.*?)` + `L(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*o(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*r(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*e(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*m(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))* (?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*i(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*p(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*s(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*u(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*m(?:\s*(?:<[^<>]+>|&#?\w+;))*\.` - the leading and trailing delimiters with optional subpatterns for tag matching and a `(.*?)` (capturing might not be necessary) inside.
- `~u` modifier is necessary since Unicode strings are to be processed.
- **UPDATE**: To account for 1+ spaces, any whitespace in the `begin` and `end` patterns can be replaced with `\s+` subpattern to match any kind of 1+ whitespace characters in the input string.
- **UPDATE 2**:  The auxiliary `$begin = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $begin);` and `$end = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $end);` are necessary to account for 1+ whitespace in the input string.
- To account for HTML entities, add another subpattern to the optional parts: `&#?\\w+;`, it will also match `&nbsp;` and `&#123;` like entities. It is also prepended with `\s*` to match optional whitespace, and quantified with `*` (can be zero or more).

Comment: That looks insane. In a positive way. Only critic would be that the opening tag just before "Hello" is missing.

Comment: That can be solved by adding the optional `(?:<[^<>]+>)?` to the start of the `$reg`. I think a tag cannot be empty, so I changed to this pattern.

Comment: When I was posting this question, I was actually hoping that Wiktor would be online with his magic. I'm testing it now. Is it possible to make it a bit less sensitive? For example, `Hello     進撃の巨人!` doesn't match because of extra white spaces. Same issue if I add white space in the html string. EDIT: extra white space is removed in this comment form. see this: https://ideone.com/lGJn98

Comment: I added an additional `preg_replace('~\s+~u', '\\s+', ...)` to make sure 1+ whitespace can be matched in the input string even if the delimiters only contain 1 whitespace. Please test, and let know if the performance is an issue.

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to make it work as suggested, see: https://ideone.com/0LdDP5 -- see the white space after `Hello`

Comment: No problem. My aim is simply to make it not too sensitive because I'm scrapping a lot of pages that use a variety of code. Some could look like this: `<p>H<div>ello</div><script></script> <em>進&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;撃の巨人</em>!</p>` -- you get the idea (and headache) :D

Comment: Thanks for the update, it ended up being complex as I suspected. Does it actually account for tags within words, see: https://ideone.com/8s6rdZ -- that has `$html = "<html>\n<body>\n<p>Hel<span>lo </span>...`

Comment: It is possible that the initial and trailing tags matched won't be "in sync", it can be helped with backreferences, but that can be a bottleneck if the opening tags are not closed in the input text. I do not have an impression that your text is proper HTML right now.

Comment: You would be surprised at the type of HTML code I've had the pleasure of processing so far. Thanks a lot for the update. I will spend a day or two to test this code on tons of sites and see how it works. I'll post an update later!

Comment: Ah right, there is a bug there. It doesn't strip the code after `$end`. If you see the ideone link you have, you can see in the output that the `</body></html>` is there. This wasn't the case earlier which is why there is probably a new error in the code?

Comment: So, the optional part should be stripped from the dynamically built regex. See the latest update

Comment: Quick question before I hit this into a cron job. See this: https://ideone.com/cyCIQ2 -- in the `$sentences` array, just remove the final white space in `$begin` and it will work. Is it possible to make it allow this type of instance? I could obviously strip `$begin` of ending whitespaces but I'm thinking there is a regex adjustment for it already?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/gNpaLC): I updated the `$begin` and `$end` preprocessing at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ran this on 10 pages and it looks like it is working so far. One issue that will likely come up is how `$end` is handled. Currently, it uses the first hit for `$end` and strips everything after it. What change do I need to do to use the last hit for `$end` instead? This is more of a curiosity than a requirement. Please let me know if I'm not making sense.

Comment: Do you mean you need to match *balanced* nested substrings? Like match up to the `$end` that corresponds to the matched `$begin`? It is possible but I guess this regex might be too resource consuming for PHP (it is already "heavy").

Comment: I have tested this on tons of sites with a variety of HTML codes and it looks like it is working very well. I do however have question about performance. Is there any chance you could give me a rundown on it and potential solutions in improving it if such exist? Thanks again for your hard work. This is a mental regex solution. =D EDIT: Please update the `$end` `$begin` variables as you did in the last demo you posted. I would updated it myself if I had enough points here.

Comment: I will think about that, but it is difficult to improve the performance when you have so "lenient" approach to matching strings. I just suggest improving the `$begin_arr` and `$end_arr` creation with just a lookahead only regex (lookbehind can be removed) with `preg_split('~(?=\X)~u', $begin, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Currently, `$begin = preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', $begin);` and `$end` part of your code doesn't work if there are spaces at the end as I noted earlier. However, the fix you added in your last ideone demo in the comment above works. It appears nonetheless that the regex isn't friendly with HTML entities. Please see this: https://ideone.com/VKXLII -- If you go to the bottom where I have set the `$begin` variable, you can see that it doesn't match the one in the `$html` code because that one has a character encoded. Is there any way to make the regex less sensitive in these cases and accept it?

Comment: I wonder why you just can't use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). It is impossible to match an HTML entity with its literal representation.

Comment: You are right, this was the obvious solution but thought I would ask regardless. Can you please update your answer with the `$begin`/`$end` fix?

Comment: I already forgot what that change looked like... I guess that was the `preg_replace_callback` introduction.

Comment: Just to highlight that so far, this has been working well on various test. We'll continue with tests. You are like the regex God here. Thanks again for posting this solution.

Comment: Really powerful regex! But do note that an HTML document does not have to have as many `<` as `>` in it. For example: `<!-- <<<< -->` or `<!-- >>>> -->` or `<p attr=">">`. Please check [this famous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @trincot: I agree, and as for comments, they are better processed before. As I mentioned in some other comment, I'd rather "prep" the input before running a cleaner, lighter regex version.

Answer (score 8):

I really wanted to write a regex solution. But I am preceeded with some nice and complex solutions. So, here is a non-regex solution.

**Short explanation:** The major problem is keeping HTML tags. We could easily search text, if HTML tags were stripped. So: strip these! We can easily search in the stripped content, and produce a substring we want to cut. Then, try to cut this substring from the HTML while keeping the tags.

**Advantages:**

- Searching is easy and independent from HTML, you can search with regex too if you need
- Requirements are scalable: you can easily add full multibyte support, support for entities and white-space collapse, and so on
- Relatively fast (it is possible, that a direct regex can be faster)
- Does not touch original HTML, and adaptable to other markup languages

**A static utility class for this scenario:**

```php
class HtmlExtractUtil
{

    const FAKE_MARKUP = '<>';
    const MARKUP_PATTERN = '#<[^>]+>#u';

    static public function extractBetween($html, $startTextToFind, $endTextToFind)
    {
        $strippedHtml = preg_replace(self::MARKUP_PATTERN, '', $html);
        $startPos = strpos($strippedHtml, $startTextToFind);
        $lastPos = strrpos($strippedHtml, $endTextToFind);

        if ($startPos === false || $lastPos === false) {
            return "";
        }

        $endPos = $lastPos + strlen($endTextToFind);
        if ($endPos <= $startPos) {
            return "";
        }

        return self::extractSubstring($html, $startPos, $endPos);
    }

    static public function extractSubstring($html, $startPos, $endPos)
    {
        preg_match_all(self::MARKUP_PATTERN, $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $start = -1;
        $end = -1;
        $previousEnd = 0;
        $stripPos = 0;
        $matchArray = $matches[0];
        $matchArray[] = [self::FAKE_MARKUP, strlen($html)];
        foreach ($matchArray as $match) {
            $diff = $previousEnd - $stripPos;
            $textLength = $match[1] - $previousEnd;
            if ($start == (-1)) {
                if ($startPos >= $stripPos && $startPos < $stripPos + $textLength) {
                    $start = $startPos + $diff;
                }
            }
            if ($end == (-1)) {
                if ($endPos > $stripPos && $endPos <= $stripPos + $textLength) {
                    $end = $endPos + $diff;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $tagLength = strlen($match[0]);
            $previousEnd = $match[1] + $tagLength;
            $stripPos += $textLength;
        }

        if ($start == (-1)) {
            return "";
        } elseif ($end == (-1)) {
            return substr($html, $start);
        } else {
            return substr($html, $start, $end - $start);
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```php
$html = '
<html>
<body>
<p>Any string before</p>
<p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
random code
random code
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>
<p>Any string after</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$startTextToFind = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
$endTextToFind = 'Lorem ipsum.';

$extractedText = HtmlExtractUtil::extractBetween($html, $startTextToFind, $endTextToFind);

header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo $extractedText . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for posting this solution *non-regex* solution. Although I will likely be going with the regex solution posted by Wiktor because it works in almost all cases I have tried, this is still extremely useful and I learned a lot with it and it will be helpful in the future.

Comment: Note that an HTML document does not have to have as many `<` as `>` in it. For example: `<!-- <<<< -->` or `<!-- >>>> -->` or `<p attr=">">`

Comment: Strange input can product strange result, even if it is literally valid. You can extend the simple `#<[^>]+>#u` (of course, do not try to write an all-case parser). If you know about strange things or you already have a strange result, then change the requirements specifically. - However, you are right.

Comment: Consider to improve your example by adding an offset instead of a simple `$endPos = strrpos(...)` . Your current code produces strange behavior e.g. on `'um', 'ip'`, returning all the source until end of file. Also when looking for `'random', 'code'`, both lines are returned, what I guess isn't the intended behavior. `$endPos = strpos($strippedHtml, $endTextToFind, $startPos+strlen($startTextToFind));` would fix that issue.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone: Good suggestion. I added a check for position order to the sample code.

Answer (score 7):

Regular expressions have their limitations when it comes to parsing HTML. Like many have done before me, I will refer to this [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

#### Potential Problems when relying on Regular Expressions

For instance, imagine this tag appears in the HTML before the part that must be extracted:

```
<p attr="Hello 進撃の巨人!">This comes before the match</p>
```

Many regexp solutions will stumble over this, and return a string that starts in the middle of this opening `p` tag.

Or consider a comment inside the HTML section that has to be matched:

```
<!-- Next paragraph will display "Lorem ipsum." -->
```

Or, some loose less-than and greater-than signs appear (let's say in a comment, or attribute value):

```
<!-- Next paragraph will display >-> << Lorem ipsum. >> -->
<p data-attr="->->->" class="myclass">
```

What will those regexes do with that?

These are just examples... there are countless other situations that pose problems to regular expression based solutions.

There are more reliable ways to parse HTML.

#### Load the HTML into a DOM

I will suggest here a solution based on the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) interface, using this algorithm:

1. Get the text content of the HTML document and identify the two offsets where both sub strings (begin/end) are located.
2. Then go through the DOM text nodes keeping track of the offsets where these nodes fit in. In the nodes where either of the two bounding offsets are crossed, a predefined delimiter (`|`) is inserted. That delimiter should not be present in the HTML string. Therefore it is doubled (`||`, `||||`, ...) until that condition is met;
3. Finally split the HTML representation by this delimiter and extract the middle part as the result.

Here is the code:

```
function extractBetween($html, $begin, $end) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    // Load HTML in DOM, making sure it supports UTF-8; double HTML tags are no problem
    $dom->loadHTML('<html><head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        </head></html>' . $html);
    // Get complete text content
    $text = $dom->textContent;
    // Get positions of the beginning/ending text; exit if not found.
    if (($from = strpos($text, $begin)) === false) return false;
    if (($to = strpos($text, $end, $from + strlen($begin))) === false) return false;
    $to += strlen($end);
    // Define a non-occurring delimiter by repeating `|` enough times:
    for ($delim = '|'; strpos($html, $delim) !== false; $delim .= $delim);
    // Use XPath to traverse the DOM
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // Go through the text nodes keeping track of total text length.
    // When exceeding one of the two offsets, inject a delimiter at that position.
    $pos = 0;
    foreach($xpath->evaluate("//text()") as $node) {
        // Add length of node's text content to total length
        $newpos = $pos + strlen($node->nodeValue);
        while ($newpos > $from || ($from === $to && $newpos === $from)) {
            // The beginning/ending text starts/ends somewhere in this text node.
            // Inject the delimiter at that position:
            $node->nodeValue = substr_replace($node->nodeValue, $delim, $from - $pos, 0);
            // If a delimiter was inserted at both beginning and ending texts,
            // then get the HTML and return the part between the delimiters
            if ($from === $to) return explode($delim, $dom->saveHTML())[1];
            // Delimiter was inserted at beginning text. Now search for ending text
            $from = $to;
        }
        $pos = $newpos;
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
// Sample input data
$html = '
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>This comes before the match</p>
        <p>Hey! Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>. la la la</p>
        <p>This comes after the match</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

$begin = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';

// Call
$html = extractBetween($html, $begin, $end);

// Output result
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.
```

You'll find this code is also easier to maintain than regex alternatives.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/560839).

Comment: This is very nice, I will put this to test and evaluate the code so that I understand it and report back when I do. Thank you very much for posting.

Comment: Btw, I suggest the following instead of str_replace: `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);`

Comment: Nice suggestion. I do notice that it then escapes non-ASCII characters to their HTML encoding. Is that OK for you?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, had to entity decode it as such: https://eval.in/559119 -- maybe your current approach is better.

Comment: Indeed, but `html_entity_decode` will also decode `&amp;` and `&lt;` (occurring in text) which would lead to invalid HTML. Would that still be acceptable? NB: I am not so happy with the way I did the replace: the `<html>` tag might not be there at all or have attributes... So I will suggest an improvement anyway.

Comment: Updated the code. It now inserts the longer `meta` tag in a separate `html` tag. This turns out to work fine. Also reduced the code a bit so that both delimiters are injected in the same code block, which is now a `while`.

Comment: I suggest, declare the delimiter inside the function, and search for it in the html first: `$delim='|@|';for($i=2;strpos($html,$delim)!==false;$i++){$delim='|@'.$i.'|';}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @DávidHorváth! I have implemented that idea now (a small variation of it).

Answer (score 5):

This might by far not be the optimal solution, but I love cracking my head about such "riddles", so here's my approach.

```
<?php
$subject = ' <html> 
<body> 
<p>He<i>l</i>lo <em>Lydia</em>!</p> 
random code 
random code 
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span>.</p> 
</body> 
</html>';

$begin = 'Hello Lydia!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';

$begin_chars = str_split($begin);
$end_chars = str_split($end);

$begin_re = '';
$end_re = '';

foreach ($begin_chars as $c) {
    if ($c == ' ') {
        $begin_re .= '(\s|(<[a-z/]+>))+';
    }
    else {
        $begin_re .= $c . '(<[a-z/]+>)?';
    }
}
foreach ($end_chars as $c) {
    if ($c == ' ') {
        $end_re .= '(\s|(<[a-z/]+>))+';
    }
    else {
        $end_re .= $c . '(<[a-z/]+>)?';
    }
}

$re = '~(.*)((' . $begin_re . ')(.*)(' . $end_re . '))(.*)~ms';

$result = preg_match( $re, $subject , $matches );
$start_tag = preg_match( '~(<[a-z/]+>)$~', $matches[1] , $stmatches );

echo $stmatches[1] . $matches[2];
```

This outputs:

```
<p>He<i>l</i>lo <em>Lydia</em>!</p> 
random code 
random code 
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span>.</p>
```

This is matching this case, but I think it would require some more logic to escape regex special chars like periods.

In general, what this snippet does:

- Splitting the strings into array, each array value representing a single character. This needs to be done because `Hello` needs to match `Hel<i>l</i>o` as well.
- To do that, for the regex part an additional `(<[a-z/]+>)?` is inserted after each character with a special case for the space character.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. Can you please update your answer with just some more details on the regex part? It's not friendly with unicode I see ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could try this RegEx:

```
(.*?)  # Data before sentences (to be removed)
(      # Capture Both sentences and text in between
  H.*?e.*?l.*?l.*?o.*?\s    # Hello[space]
  (<.*?>)*                  # Optional Opening Tag(s)
  進.*?撃.*?の.*?巨.*?人.*?   # 進撃の巨人
  (<\/.*?>)*                # Optional Closing Tag(s)
  (.*?)                     # Optional Data in between sentences
  (<.*?>)*                  # Optional Opening Tag(s)
  L.*?o.*?r.*?e.*?m.*?\s    # Lorem[space]
  (<.*?>)*                  # Optional Opening Tag(s)
  i.*?p.*?s.*?u.*?m.*?      # ipsum
)
(.*)   # Data after sentences (to be removed)
```

Substituting with the **`2nd` Capture Group**

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/rP0lP1/1)</kbd>

The Regex can be shortened to:

```
(.*?)(H.*?e.*?l.*?l.*?o.*?\s(<.*?>)*進.*?撃.*?の.*?巨.*?人.*?(<\/.*?>)*(.*?)(<.*?>)*L.*?o.*?r.*?e.*?m.*?\s(<.*?>)*i.*?p.*?s.*?u.*?m.*?)(.*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was pretty intense. :) Can you please write this approach in PHP form, using the variables, stripping the HTML etc. Currently, the sentences are *hardcoded* in your regex.

Comment: This would match also strings like `HellSOMETHINGo etc...`

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun

```
<?php
$begin = 'Hello Moto!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';
//https://regex101.com/r/mC8aO6/1
$re = "/[\\w\\W]/"; 
$str = $begin.$end; 
$subst = "$0.*?"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
//Hello Moto! 
//to
//H.*?e.*?l.*?l.*?o.*? .*?M.*?o.*?t.*?o.*?!.*?

//https://regex101.com/r/fS6zG2/1
$re = "/(\\!|\\.\\.)/"; 
$str = $result; 
$subst = "\\\\$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

$re = "/.*(<p.*?$result.*?p>).*/s"; 
$str = "        <html>\n        <body>\n        <p>He<i>l</i>lo <em>Moto</em>!\n        random code\n        random code\n        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.<p>\n        </body>\n        </html>\n        "; 
$subst = "$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result."\n";
?>
```

Input

```
$begin = 'Hello Moto!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';

    <html>
    <body>
    <p>He<i>l</i>lo <em>Moto</em>!
    random code
    random code
    <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.<p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Output

```
<p>He<i>l</i>lo <em>Moto</em>!
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.<p>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
$escape=array('\\'=>1,'^'=>1,'?'=>1,'+'=>1,'*'=>1,'{'=>1,'}'=>1,'('=>1,')'=>1,'['=>1,']'=>1,'|'=>1,'.'=>1,'$'=>1,'+'=>1,'/'=>1);
$pattern='/';
for($i=0;isset($begin[$i]);$i++){
if(ord($c=$begin[$i])<0x80||ord($c)>0xbf){
    if(isset($escape[$c]))
        $pattern.="([ \t\r\n\v\f]*<\\/?[a-zA-Z]+>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*)*\\$c";
    else
        $pattern.="([ \t\r\n\v\f]*<\\/?[a-zA-Z]+>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*)*$c";
    }
    else
        $pattern.=$c;
}
$pattern.="(.|\n|\r)*";
for($i=0;isset($end[$i]);$i++){
if(ord($c=$end[$i])<0x80||ord($c)>0xbf){
    if(isset($escape[$c]))
        $pattern.="([ \t\r\n\v\f]*<\\/?[a-zA-Z]+>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*)*\\$c";
    else
        $pattern.="([ \t\r\n\v\f]*<\\/?[a-zA-Z]+>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*)*$c";
    }
    else
        $pattern.=$c;
}
$pattern[17]='?';
$pattern.='(<\\/?[a-zA-Z]+>)?/';
preg_match($pattern,$html,$a);
$match=$a[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several different approaches to do a content search on HTML source. They all have advantages and disadvantages. If the structure in unknown code is an issue, the safest way would be to use an XML parser, however, those are complex and therefore rather slow.

Regular expressions are designed for text processing. Although regexp is not the quickest thing due to overhead, `preg_`functions are a reasonable compromise to keep code small and concise while not paying to much performance impact if and only if you prevent patterns becoming too complex.

Analysis of HTML structures is doable by recursive regular expressions. Since the slow down the processing and are hard to debug I prefer to code the base logic in PHP and utilize `preg_`functions to do smaller quick tasks.

Here is an solution in OOP, a tiny class intended to process many searches on the same HTML source. It is already an approach to handle extended similar problems like adding preceding and succeeding content until next tag boundary. It does not claim to be a perfect solution yet, but it is easily extendable.

The logic is:
Pay some runtime for initialization to store tag positions relative to plain text, strip tags and store the strings between `<...>` and sums of length as well.
Then on each content search match the needles with plain content. Locate the start/end position in the HTML source by binary search.

Binary search works like that: A sorted list is required. You store the index of first and last element+1. Calculate the average by an addition and integer division by 2. Division and floor is performantly done by a right bitshift. If the found value is to low, set the less index var to the current index, else the greater one. Stop on index difference 1. If you search an exact value, break early on element found.
0,(14+1) => 7 ; 7,15 => 11 ; 7,11 => 9 ; 7,9 => 8 ; 8-7 = diff.1
Instead of 15 iterations only 4 are done. The greater the start value is, the more time is exponentially saved.

**PHP class:**

```
<?php
class HtmlTextSearch
{
  protected 
    $html            = '',
    $heystack        = '',
    $tags            = [],
    $current_tag_idx = null
  ;

  const
    RESULT_NO_MODIFICATION      = 0,
    RESULT_PREPEND_TAG          = 1,
    RESULT_PREPEND_TAG_CONTENT  = 2,
    RESULT_APPEND_TAG           = 4,
    RESULT_APPEND_TAG_CONTENT   = 8,
    MATCH_CASE_INSENSITIVE      =16,
    MATCH_BLANK_AS_WHITESPACE   =32,
    MATCH_BLANK_MULTIPLE        =64
  ;

  public function __construct($html)
  {
    $this->set_html($html);
  }

  public function set_html($html)
  {
    $this->html = $html;
    $regexp = '~<.*?>~su';
    preg_match_all($regexp, $html, $this->tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $this->tags = $this->tags[0];
    # we use exact the same algorithm to strip html
    $this->heystack = preg_replace($regexp, '', $html);

    # convert positions to plain content
    $sum_length = 0;
    foreach($this->tags as &$tag)
    { $tag['pos_in_content'] = $tag[1] - $sum_length;
      $tag['sum_length'    ] = $sum_length += strlen($tag[0]);
    }

    # zero length dummy tags to mark start/end position of strings not beginning/ending with a tag
    array_unshift($this->tags , [0 => '', 1 => 0, 'pos_in_content' => 0, 'sum_length' => 0 ]); 
    array_push   ($this->tags , [0 => '', 1 => strlen($html)-1]); 
  }

  public function translate_pos_plain2html($content_position)
  {
    # binary search
    $idx = [true => 0, false => count($this->tags)-1];
    while(1 < $idx[false] - $idx[true])
    { $i = ($idx[true] + $idx[false]) >>1;                               // integer half of both array indexes
      $idx[$this->tags[$i]['pos_in_content'] <= $content_position] = $i; // hold one index less and the other greater
    }

    $this->current_tag_idx = $idx[true];
    return $this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx]['sum_length'] + $content_position;
  }

  public function &find_content($needle_start, $needle_end = '', $result_modifiers = self::RESULT_NO_MODIFICATION)
  {
    $needle_start = preg_quote($needle_start, '~');
    $needle_end   = '' == $needle_end ? '' : preg_quote($needle_end  , '~');
    if((self::MATCH_BLANK_MULTIPLE | self::MATCH_BLANK_AS_WHITESPACE) & $result_modifiers)
    { 
      $replacement  = self::MATCH_BLANK_AS_WHITESPACE & $result_modifiers ? '\s' : ' ';
      if(self::MATCH_BLANK_MULTIPLE & $result_modifiers)
      { $replacement .= '+';
        $multiplier = '+';
      }
      else
        $multiplier = '';
      $repl_pattern = "~ $multiplier~";
      $needle_start = preg_replace($repl_pattern, $replacement, $needle_start);
      $needle_end   = preg_replace($repl_pattern, $replacement, $needle_end);
    }

    $icase = self::MATCH_CASE_INSENSITIVE & $result_modifiers ? 'i' : '';
    $search_pattern = "~{$needle_start}.*?{$needle_end}~su$icase";
    preg_match_all($search_pattern, $this->heystack, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    foreach($matches[0] as &$match)
    { $pre = $post = '';

      $pos_start = $this->translate_pos_plain2html($match[1]);
      if(self::RESULT_PREPEND_TAG_CONTENT & $result_modifiers)
        $pos_start = $this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx][1]
          +( self::RESULT_PREPEND_TAG & $result_modifiers ? 0 : strlen ($this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx][0]) );
      elseif(self::RESULT_PREPEND_TAG     & $result_modifiers)
        $pre = $this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx][0];

      $pos_end   = $this->translate_pos_plain2html($match[1] + strlen($match[0]));
      if(self::RESULT_APPEND_TAG_CONTENT & $result_modifiers)
      { $next_tag = $this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx+1];
        $pos_end = $next_tag[1]
          +( self::RESULT_APPEND_TAG  & $result_modifiers ? strlen ($next_tag[0]) : 0);
      }
      elseif(self::RESULT_APPEND_TAG     & $result_modifiers)
        $post = $this->tags[$this->current_tag_idx+1][0];

      $match = $pre . substr($this->html, $pos_start, $pos_end - $pos_start) . $post;
    };
    return $matches[0];
  }
}
```

**Some test case:**

```
$html_source = get($_POST['html'], <<< ___
<html>
  <body>
    <p>He said: "Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!"</p>
    random code
    random code
    <p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span>. foo bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
___
);


  function get(&$ref, $default=null) { return isset($ref) ? $ref : $default; }

  function attr_checked($name, $method = "post")
  { $req = ['post' => '_POST', 'get' => '_GET'];
    return isset($GLOBALS[$req[$method]][$name]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
  }

  $begin = get($_POST['begin'], '"Hello 進撃の巨人!"');
  $end   = get($_POST['end'  ], 'Lorem ipsum.'   );
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="html" cols="80" rows="10"><?php
echo $html_source;
?></textarea>

  <br><input type="text"  name="begin" value="<?php echo $begin;?>">
  <br><input type="text"  name="end"   value="<?php echo $end  ;?>">

  <br><input type="checkbox" name="tag-pre" id="tag-pre"<?php echo attr_checked('tag-pre');?>>
      <label for="tag-pre">prefix tag</label>
      <br><input type="checkbox" name="txt-pre" id="txt-pre"<?php echo attr_checked('txt-pre');?>>
      <label for="txt-pre">prefix content</label>
  <br><input type="checkbox" name="txt-suf" id="txt-suf"<?php echo attr_checked('txt-suf');?>>
      <label for="txt-suf">suffix content</label>
  <br><input type="checkbox" name="tag-suf" id="tag-suf"<?php echo attr_checked('tag-suf');?>>
      <label for="tag-suf">suffix tag</label>
  <br>
  <br><input type="checkbox" name="wspace" id="wspace"<?php echo attr_checked('wspace');?>>
      <label for="wspace">blanc (#32) matches any whitespace character</label>
  <br><input type="checkbox" name="multiple" id="wspace"<?php echo attr_checked('multiple');?>>
      <label for="multiple">one or more blancs match any number of blancs/whitespaces</label>
  <br><input type="checkbox" name="icase"    id="icase"<?php echo attr_checked('icase');?>>
      <label for="icase">case insensitive</label>

  <br><button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<?php
  $html = new HtmlTextSearch($html_source);

  $opts=
  [ 'tag-pre' => HtmlTextSearch::RESULT_PREPEND_TAG,
    'txt-pre' => HtmlTextSearch::RESULT_PREPEND_TAG_CONTENT,
    'txt-suf' => HtmlTextSearch::RESULT_APPEND_TAG_CONTENT,
    'tag-suf' => HtmlTextSearch::RESULT_APPEND_TAG,
    'wspace'  => HtmlTextSearch::MATCH_BLANK_AS_WHITESPACE,
    'multiple'=> HtmlTextSearch::MATCH_BLANK_MULTIPLE,
    'icase'   => HtmlTextSearch::MATCH_CASE_INSENSITIVE
  ];
  $options = 0;
  foreach($opts as $k => $v)
    if(isset($_POST[$k]))
      $options |= $v;
  $results = $html->find_content($begin, $end, $options);
  var_dump($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP solution:

[PHPFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0vk7-n6n3)

```
$html = '
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        random code
        random code
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
$begin = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';

$matchHtmlTag = '(?:<.*?>)?';
$matchAllNonGreedy = '(?:.|\r?\n)*?';
$matchUnescapedCharNotAtEnd = '([^\\\\](?!$)|\\.(?!$))';
$matchBeginWithTags = preg_replace(
    $matchUnescapedCharNotAtEnd, '$0' . $matchHtmlTag, preg_quote($begin));
$matchEndWithTags = preg_replace(
    $matchUnescapedCharNotAtEnd, '$0' . $matchHtmlTag, preg_quote($end));
$pattern = '/' . $matchBeginWithTags . $matchAllNonGreedy . $matchEndWithTags . '/';

preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
$html = $matches[0];
```

## Generated regex ($pattern):

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE0pR5/1)

`H(?:<.*?>)?e(?:<.*?>)?l(?:<.*?>)?l(?:<.*?>)?o(?:<.*?>)? (?:<.*?>)?進(?:<.*?>)?撃(?:<.*?>)?の(?:<.*?>)?巨(?:<.*?>)?人(?:<.*?>)?!(?:.|\r?\n)*?L(?:<.*?>)?o(?:<.*?>)?r(?:<.*?>)?e(?:<.*?>)?m(?:<.*?>)? (?:<.*?>)?i(?:<.*?>)?p(?:<.*?>)?s(?:<.*?>)?u(?:<.*?>)?m(?:<.*?>)?\.`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `random code` in your example is inside `<p></p>` i propose using domdocument and xpath and not regular expression in what you try to do.

```
$html = '
        <html>
        <body>
        <div>nada blahhh <p>test paragraph</p> <em>blahh</em></div>
        <p>test</p>
        <span>this is test</span>
        <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
        <p>random code</p>
        <p>random code</p>
        <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>
        <div>nada blahhh <p>test paragraph</p> <em>blahh</em></div>
        <p>test</p>
        <span>this is test</span>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
$begin = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
$begin = iconv ( 'iso-8859-1','utf-8' , $begin ); // had to use iconv it won't be needed in your case
$end = 'Lorem ipsum.';       
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// example 3: same as above with wildcard
$elements = $xpath->query("*/p");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    $flag = 'no_output';
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
      if($flag=='prepare_for_output'){$flag='output';}
      if($element->nodeValue==$begin){
      $flag='prepare_for_output';
      }
      if($element->nodeValue==$end){
      $flag='no_output';
      }
      if($flag=='output') {
      echo $element->nodeValue."\n";
      }
  }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa1095d98c6ef5c600f7b06366b4e0c4798a112f

Answer (score 2):

you can use this concept , code are given below

```
        <html lang="en-US">
        <head>

        <title>HTML Unicode UTF-8</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>
        <?php
        $html = '
            <html>
            <body>
            <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
            random code
            random code
            <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>

            </body>
            </html>
            ';

        $begin = 'Hello 進撃の巨人!';
        $end = 'Lorem ipsum.';

        $stripped =strip_tags($html);

        if (strpos($stripped, $end) !== false) {

            $final =str_replace($begin,"",$stripped);

           echo str_replace($end,"",$final);
        }
        ?>
        </body>  
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't break your mind trying to use regexp.

Use the DOM library of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $html = '
            <html>
            <body>
            <p>Hello <em>進撃の巨人</em>!</p>
            random code
            random code
            <p>Lorem <span>ipsum<span>.</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ';

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    $body_elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body"); 

    $code = '';

    foreach ($body_elements as $element) { 

        $children  = $element->childNodes;

        foreach ($children as $child) 
        { 
            $code.= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }

    }

    echo $code;
?>
```

If you run that code in a php sample file, you should check the source of the webpage using "View Source" in your browser to see the html tags. The <p> or <em> should be there ;-)